# Prove the validity of a triple

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, loop-invariant

To prove the validity of this valid triple:

```
{X==U, Y==0, U > 0, N > 0}
    while (X > 0) { X = X - N; Y = Y + 1;};
{Y == ⌈U/N⌉}
```

What is the loop invariant?